# java restful web service image gallery

Tags: java, web-services, rest, gallery

i have a project where i'm dealing with restful web service, especially need to return images for android client, when client is entering the "gallery" he need to get a root collection which have to return all of folders and file(images) from static folder on running server. Can someone help with this? How can i return images that could be accessed by client for detailed view?

Comment: You are asking a very general question.  Google some and find some tutorials for what you want, then try some things on your own.  Once you have a specific problem, come back and ask about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to getHttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse type of object and apply below code -

```
        String filePath = request.getParameter(YOUR_FILE_PATH_PARAMETER");
        String filePath = filePath;
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="
                + "YOUR_FILE_NAME");

        // Get it from file system
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));


        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
        // copy binary content to output stream
        while (in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1) {
            out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);

                        in.close();
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
```